# gfortran default width/decimal number descriptors

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

The following code demonstrates that for gfortran one may have the processor decide the width of the format descriptor for an integer and floating point number:

```
program test
    double precision :: x = 5.321568756
    integer ::  i = 53254
    write(*, '(I0)') i
    write(*, '(F0.3)') x
end program test
```

When compiled, this code outputs

```
53254
5.322
```

Is it also possible to have the processor decide on the number of decimal points that are output with the `write` statement? In other words, to have the above program output the following:

```
53254
5.321568756
```

without explicitly providing the number of decimal points in the format descriptor like `'(F0.9)'`. Something like `'(F0.(default number of decimal points here))'`

Comment: What do you mean by "default number of decimal points here".  Recall that `x` probably isn't exactly 5.321568756 (and also `5.321568756` is default real not single precision).

Comment: I've removed the part about `.f90` and free-form from the text (but left the f90 tag).  Those don't seem relevant to me, but add back if you really think they are.

Comment: If you use list directed I/O (the * format), the compiler will choose its default representation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `g0` edit descriptor, like:

```
program test
  double precision :: x = 5.321568756
  integer ::  i = 53254
  write(*, '(I0)') i
  write(*, '(F0.3)') x
  write(*, '(G0)') x
end program test
```

(The difference between the G and F edit descriptors is that when the value gets large/small enough, the G edit descriptor switches to exponential notation. Usually that's what you want, though)